# Why does my StringFormat not work in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I've seen a few questions like this on SO but none of the answers work for me! Here's my abridged code:

```
<Grid Margin="10,4,2,3">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Name="myImage" />

    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" >
        <Label x:Name="labelDimensions" Content="Image Dimensions" />
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Column="0" 
                   x:Name="imageWidth" 
                   Content="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, 
                             ElementName=myImage, 
                             StringFormat={}{0:1234.5}}" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1" x:Name="label3" Content=" x " />
            <Label Grid.Column="2" 
                   x:Name="imageHeight" 
                   Content="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, 
                             ElementName=myImage, 
                             StringFormat={}{0:1234.5}}" />
        </Grid>
    </WrapPanel>

</Grid>
```

I am expecting to see, below the 'Image Dimensions' label, something like "641.3 x 480.0" but no matter what I do, it comes out with stuff like "641.30000000 x 480".

I've formats like {0:1234.5} and {0:#,#.#} but nether have any effect. I've also tried ConentStringFormat as one SO answer suggested but that didn't even compile.

Any advice would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Apparently, they are needed if you have no leading plain text in your format. Without them, it doesn't compile.

Comment: Have you tried `{0:F1}`? (See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).)

Comment: I have now. As I resize it, I get things like "639.00000 x 426.00000", so no difference. I don't think it is the format string itself, something else seems to be making WPF completely ignore it.

Comment: Cheers guys, the linked question had the answer (as did the other I had read, I just didn't make the right connections). Once I used a TextBlock *instead of* a label, StringFormat worked. ContentStringFormat didn't compile though, maybe I am targeting the wrong .Net version.

Comment: `ContentStringFormat` is not inside the binding. It is a Control property by itself. `<Label Content="{Binding LastModTs}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:dd.MM.yyy HH:mm}" />`

Answer (score 7):

Use the `ContentStringFormat` instead.

`StringFormat` is only used when binding to a property of type `String`. The `Content` property of `Label` is of type object as you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx), so `StringFormat` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `StringFormat={}{0:F1}` :

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" 
       x:Name="imageWidth" 
       Content="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, 
                 ElementName=myImage, 
                 StringFormat={}{0:F1}" />
<Label Grid.Column="1" x:Name="label3" Content=" x " />
<Label Grid.Column="2" 
        x:Name="imageHeight" 
        Content="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, 
                  ElementName=myImage, 
                  StringFormat={}{0:F1}" />
```